# How do I stop the comments going to my email?

Tags: comments

Want to be able to disallow comments from going to my email.

Thanks
Jo

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to login to your WordPress admin area and go to Settings » Discussion page. From here, scroll down to ‘E-mail me whenever’ section where you will see these two checkbox options:

- Anyone posts a comment
- A comment is held for moderation

[image]

Ref: https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-turn-off-comments-notification-in-wordpress/